# awk replacement using specific values in two columns

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
20:60479_C_T 60479 C T  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
20:60522_T_TC 60522 T TC        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
20:60568_A_C 60568 A C  0 0 1 0 0 1 
20:60571_C_A 60571 C A  0 1 0 1 0 0 
20:60579_G_A 60579 G A  0 0 1 0 0 0
```

My current file is bigger with 3 million rows and 3,000 columns. I want to use the values in columns `$3` and `$4` to replace `0` and `1` in the rest of columns. The desired output would be:

```
20:60479_C_T 60479 C T  C C C C C T C T
20:60522_T_TC 60522 T TC        T T T T T T T 
20:60568_A_C 60568 A C  A A C A A C 
20:60571_C_A 60571 C A  C A C A C C 
20:60579_G_A 60579 G A  G G A G G G
```

I know how to do it for a couple of columns:

```
awk '{d["0"]=$3; d["1"]=$4; print "20", $1, "0", $2, d[$5], d[$6];}' myfile
```

But I don't know how to do it automatically for all the columns and avoid adding all the columns manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a variable number of columns, you can probably get away with something like:

```
awk <testprog.in '{for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++){$i = $($i+3)}print}'
```

The "magic" here is the assigning of `$($i+3)` to `$i` for all values of `i` between 5 and the field count (inclusive).

The expression `$i+3` will turn `0` and `1` into `3` and `4` respectively and so the next step will be evaluating `$3` or `$4` (the `C` and `T` in the first line for example) and using that to replace the item.

The output of you small test case is, as expected:

```
20:60479_C_T 60479 C T C C C C C T C T
20:60522_T_TC 60522 T TC T T T T T T T
20:60568_A_C 60568 A C A A C A A C
20:60571_C_A 60571 C A C A C A C C
20:60579_G_A 60579 G A G G A G G G
```

You will, of course, need to check the *performance* of this with your larger data sets. On my box, a three-million-line file with 3000 entries each takes about half an hour.

Compare that with a C program (although admittedly quick'n'dirty, heavily tied to your *specific* input data, without what I would generally consider necessary error checking) which only takes about ten minutes.

For completeness, here's the C variant which, assuming it's called `prog.c`, you can compile with something like `gcc -o prog prog.c` and run with something like `./prog <testprog.in`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static char buff[102040];

static char *getStr(char *buff, int *pSz) {
    if (*buff == 0) return NULL;

    char *nextBuff = buff;
    while ((nextBuff[0] != 0) && isspace(nextBuff[0])) {
        nextBuff++;
    }
    if (*nextBuff == 0) return NULL;

    *pSz = 0;
    while ((nextBuff[*pSz] != 0) && ! isspace(nextBuff[*pSz])) {
        (*pSz)++;
    }

    return nextBuff;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str, *str3, *str4; int sz, sz3, sz4;

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {
        str = getStr(buff, &sz); printf("%*.*s", sz, sz, str);
        str = getStr(str + sz, &sz); printf(" %*.*s", sz, sz, str);
        str3 = getStr(str + sz, &sz3); printf(" %*.*s", sz3, sz3, str3); 
        str4 = getStr(str3 + sz3, &sz4); printf(" %*.*s", sz4, sz4, str4);

        str = getStr(str4 + sz4, &sz);
        while (str != NULL) {
            if (*str == '0') {
                printf(" %*.*s", sz3, sz3, str3);
            } else {
                printf(" %*.*s", sz4, sz4, str4);
            }
            str = getStr(str + sz, &sz);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @paxdiablo, I am quite new at C, do I need to compile the program, right? could you add a line to the answer about how to run it if my file is named `file.txt`? thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: @user2380782, have added notes on how to do that just before the C code section.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{d[0]=$3; d[1]=$4; for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) $i=d[$i]} 1' file
20:60479_C_T 60479 C T C C C C C T C T
20:60522_T_TC 60522 T TC T T T T T T T
20:60568_A_C 60568 A C A A C A A C
20:60571_C_A 60571 C A C A C A C C
20:60579_G_A 60579 G A G G A G G G
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` in `awk` you could try this as an option:

```
$ awk '{d[1]=$1;d[2]=$2;gsub(/0/,$3);gsub(/1/,$4);$1=d[1];$2=d[2];}1' myfile
20:60479_C_T 60479 C T C C C C C T C T
20:60522_T_TC 60522 T TC T T T T T T T
20:60568_A_C 60568 A C A A C A A C
20:60571_C_A 60571 C A C A C A C C
20:60579_G_A 60579 G A G G A G G G
```

Comment: Apologies, Gioconda, I mistakenly thought your later lines had too many columns (miscounted because of the `$3` and `$4`) then, when I figured *out* my mistake, my downvote had been locked in. So, if you're wondering why I made a seemingly irrelevant edit, it was so I could reverse said downvote. Again, apologies, just thought I'd better explain.

Comment: It'll probably be OK given the OPs sample data and assuming all her other data is similar but it would fail if $3 or $4 contained an ampersand (`&`)